# Why is this Postgres query throwing "duplicate key value violates unique constraint"?

Tags: postgresql

I've implemented simple update/insert query like this:

```
-- NOTE: :time is replaced in real code, ids are placed statically for example purposes
-- set status_id=1 to existing rows, update others
UPDATE account_addresses
SET status_id = 1, updated_at = :time
WHERE account_id = 1
  AND address_id IN (1,2,3)
  AND status_id IN (2);

-- filter values according to what that update query returns, i.e. construct query like this to insert remaining new records:
INSERT INTO account_addresses (account_id, address_id, status_id, created_at, updated_at)
SELECT account_id, address_id, status_id, created_at::timestamptz, updated_at::timestamptz
FROM (VALUES (1,1,1,:time,:time),(1,2,1,:time,:time)) AS sub(account_id, address_id, status_id, created_at, updated_at)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM account_addresses AS aa2
  WHERE aa2.account_id = sub.account_id AND aa2.address_id = sub.address_id
)
RETURNING id;

-- throws:
-- PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "..."
-- DETAIL:  Key (account_id, address_id)=(1, 1) already exists.
```

The reason why I'm doing it this way is: the record MAY exist with `status_id=2`. If so, set `status_id=1`.
Then insert new records. If it already exists, but was not affected by first UPDATE query, ignore it (i.e. rows with `status_id=3`).

This works nicely, but doing it concurrently, it crashes on duplicate key in race condition.
But why is race condition occurring, if I'm trying to do that "insert-where-not-exists" atomically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah. I just searched a little more and insert where not exists is not atomic.

Quote from http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/26970.1296761016@sss.pgh.pa.us :

> Mage  writes:
>
> > The main question is that isn't "insert into ... select ... where not 
> >     exists" atomic?
>
> No, it isn't: it *will* fail in the presence of other transactions
>   doing the same thing, because the EXISTS test will only see rows that
>   committed before the command started.  You might care to read the
>   manual's chapter about concurrency:
>   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/mvcc.html

Comment: @Houari yea. I know... My bad. Facepalm.

Comment: Just FYI, this is not a question of atomicity, it's a matter of transaction isolation.